# Can I change JVM parameters during execution

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I am writing a Java program and at some point during execution I want to change the JVM settings (decrease the heap) and after a while increase it again. Is it possible with Java?

Comment: Can I ask _why_ you'd want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: you can't. Heap size is fixed once you are running it, and there's no way to modify it from the code.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible, but you could of course control the heap with **-Xmx** or **-Xms**.
You can also play with : **-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio** : this is the maximum percentage (70 by default if I am no mistaken) of the heap that is free before GC will shrink it.

Giving a small -Xms will make the heap grow (if needed and will involve a full GC) and shrink back is possible also.

Generally people try to avoid as much as possible this shrinking and growing because it involves a gull GC aka stop-the-world events that will slow you down.